# как... пить воду?

Tags: пунктуация

на 28м году задумался..вот как пить воду,там ж рыбки тр@хаются...да и не только они!

Comment: Вообще-то, здесь вопросы по русскому языку обсуждают, Вам на другой сайт

Comment: О, к 28 годам наконец-то достиг уровня прыщавых подростков.